# Add info using textbox into gridview after retrieving data from database C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, datagridview, textbox

I'm retrieving data from database into the grid for 5 column, there is another 3 columns beside that which I want to fill in using textbox input (using different button).

How to fetch the input from the textbox into the grid after I retrieve the data from database?

Here is the front looks like:

[image]

Here is the coding:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="BNE No: "></asp:Label>
    &nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="BNE No: "></asp:Label>
    &nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Search From Database" />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> 
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> 
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Insert to Grid" OnClick="Button3_Click" />
    <br />
    <%--<asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server">
    </asp:Table>--%>

     <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">

            <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="BNE No">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("BNENo") %>'></asp:Label>  
                    </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField> 
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ECN No">
                <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("KVNo") %>'></asp:Label>  
                    </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rec Date">
                <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("ReceivedDate") %>'></asp:Label>  
                    </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Issued Date">
                <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("IssuedDate") %>'></asp:Label>  
                    </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Status") %>'></asp:Label>  
                    </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Location">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text=''></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Time">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text=''></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text=''></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
     </asp:GridView>
</div>
</form>
```

Here is the behind code where I use to retrieve the data by using button 1

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//this Button use To call multiple data from database named tblBNE into GridView
{
    count = 0;
    con.Open();

    OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [BNENo],[KVNo],[ReceivedDate],[IssuedDate],[Status] FROM [tblBNE] where BNENo='" + TextBox1.Text + "' or BNENo='" + TextBox2.Text + "' ";

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dt);

    count = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows.Count.ToString());

    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();

    con.Close();

    if (count == 0)
    {
        Label3.Text = "record not found";
    }
}
```

So, I want to use button 3 = insert to grid to fill into label9 to 11 using textbox3 to 5. How can I  do that?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **never EVER** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: Ditto to @marc_s comment. It is difficult to understand exactly what you are asking, are you trying to “filter” the grid from the text in text boxes OR trying to “Add New” items to the grid from the text in the text boxes? Your question sounds like you want to add new items, however the code looks like a filter.

Comment: What are those textboxes  for? Location, time and date? You want the values entered in these textboxes  to be applied to all the rows in the girdview?

Comment: @marc_s I will check about that TQ..

Comment: @JohnG yes I want to add new item to the gridview after I retrieve data from database (add additional info to the data from database and insert the data to database back) is this clear to you? :)

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya yes Textbox3 for location, textbox4 for time and textbox5 for date. yes I want the values to be applied to all rows in column location, date and time. TQ

Comment: is there anyone who could help me for this?